# Rename a certain key in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a column `car_details` with 2000 entries, each of which is a hash of info that looks like this:

```
{"capacity"=>"0",
 "wheels"=>"6",
 "weight"=>"3000",
 "engine_type"=>"Diesel",
 "horsepower"=>"350",
 "fuel_capacity"=>"35",
 "fuel_consumption"=>"30"}
```

Some cars have more details, some have less.  I want to rename the `"fuel_consumption"` key to `"mpg"` on every car that has that key.

Comment: Is this `column` in the DB? (ie. Is this hash serialized?) or are you doing this manipulation just in memory?

Comment: It's on the DB, its a HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to update a serialized column in a data table en masse with raw SQL. The best way I can think of would be to do something like:

```
Car.find_each do |car|
  mpg = car.car_details.delete("fuel_consumption")
  car.car_details["mpg"] = mpg if mpg
  car.save
end
```

This is assuming that you are using Active Record and your model is called "Car".

Answer (score 2):

Well, a previous answer will generate 2000 requests, but you can use the `REPLACE` function instead. Both MySQL and PostgreSQL have that, so it will be like:

```
Car.update_all("car_details = REPLACE(car_details, 'fuel_consumption', 'mpg')")
```

Take a look at the [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) method for the conditions.

See also [PostgreSQL string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) and [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: I've just checked this query on my local mysql database with 480 000 rows, and query took 14 seconds.

Comment: What options would you pass to skip over car_details without the fuel_consumption key?

Comment: well, it won't update rows that dont contain fuel_consumption at all, so you don't need any additional conditions

Comment: I suppose it may be unlikely based on your dataset, but if any other part of the hash (keys or values) contained "fuel_consumption" that would also be renamed to "mpg" by this command.

Answer (score 2):

Answer posted by @Ivan Shamatov works very well and is particular important to have good performances on huge databases.

I tried it with a PostgreSQL database, on a jsonb column.
**To let it works we have to pay same attention to data type casting.**

For example on a `User` model like this:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base {
                   :id => :integer,
           :created_at => :datetime,
           :updated_at => :datetime,
                :email => :string,
           :first_name => :string,
            :last_name => :string,
          :custom_data => :jsonb
}
```

My goal was to rename a key, inside `custom_data` jsonb field.
For example `custom_data` hash content from:

```
{
                "foo" => "bar",
           "date" => "1980-07-10"
}
```

to:

```
{
                "new_foo" => "bar",
             "date" => "1980-07-10"
}
```

For all users records present into my db.

We can execute this query:

```
old_key = 'foo'
new_key = 'new_foo'    
User.update_all("custom_data = REPLACE(custom_data::text, '#{old_key}'::text, '#{new_key}'::text)::jsonb")
```

This will only replace the target key (old_key), inside our jsonb hash, without changing hash values or other hash keys.

Note `::text` and `::jsonb` type casting!